# How to implement digital signature validation in spring web service for different clients?

Tags: java, web-services, spring-ws, ws-security

I have a requirement to validate the digital signature of the SOAP request using X509 certificates for a spring based webservice that accepts requests from multiple vendors.

What is the general strategy for implementing such a security? Should I create one webservice for each vendor so that I can validate the digital signature based on the public key of the caller? Ideally I would like to just have one webservice as the content of each vendor request has the same schema.

Answer (score 0):

The digital signature for SOAP messages is embedded into the SOAP header of the message. This is a simplified schema of a message. (See a full example [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGMCP_5.1.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.webservices.doc/wsSecurity/dfhws_soapmsg_signed.html))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
 <wsse:Security 
    <wsse:BinarySecurityToken />
    <ds:Signature>
        <ds:SignedInfo> 
        <ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
 </wsse:Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body> 
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The signature allows to know the identity of the signer referencing the x509 certificate used to sign.

You do not need different webservice for each vendor. **To allow access, request the public part of the certificate to the vendor that is going to be used to sign messages. When a soap message is received, compare the signer certificate with the expected one.**

To simplify comparison, you can check serialnumber+issuer